# Are rc.shutdown and rc.shutdown.local still usable on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, shutdown

Are either of `rc.shutdown` or `rc.shutdown.local` still being use in OS X, or have they been replaced with something else?

I realize that `launchd` is replacing most of this, but I thought you could still use `rc.shutdown.local` to run a script.

I couldn't even find rc.shutdown anywhere on my system.

Comment: There is a mention of `/etc/rc.shutdown.local` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.SystemStarter.plist`, but I am not at all sure what it means. The manual page for `SystemStarter` is not a great help, beyond informing us that it is deprecated. The program is running on my system, though. Oh, and the string `/etc/rc.shutdown.local` is found inside the `SystemStarter` binary. My guess is that files there will be run at shutdown.

Comment: Your wish is my ⌘.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea, really. There is a mention of `/etc/rc.shutdown.local` in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.SystemStarter.plist`, but I am not at all sure what it means. The manual page for `SystemStarter` is not a great help, beyond informing us that it is deprecated. The program is running on my system, though. Oh, and the string `/etc/rc.shutdown.local` is found inside the `SystemStarter` binary as well. My guess is that files there will be run at shutdown.

But if I may answer your implicit question of how to run something at shutdown: Here is what I have done. First, I wrote and compiled this little C program. What it does is simply to sleep until it receives a SIGTERM, at which point it exec's its arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

char **args;

void sigterm(int s) {
  execvp(args[1],args+1);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s: exec failed: ", args[0]);
  perror(args[1]);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  args=argv;
  signal(SIGTERM,sigterm);
  for (;;) sleep(0x7FFFFFFF);
}
```

I have a launch daemon set up to run this program at startup. Come shutdown time, `launchd` will send the SIGTERM that causes the program to do its thing. Of course, it has to do so fairly quickly, or `launchd` will apply a bigger sledgehammer.

Here is my `launchctl` plist, named `no.ntnu.math.hanche.quietboot.plist` and placed in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`. Its sole purpose is to run `nvram SystemAdioVolume=%01' at shutdown, so I can reboot without the chime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>no.ntnu.math.hanche.quietboot</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/local/bin/atshutdown</string>
        <string>/usr/sbin/nvram</string>
        <string>SystemAudioVolume=%01</string>
    </array>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: That's really cool :-). +1.  I'm really looking for info on those files though, because I'm trying to get a better understanding of what happened to those files and if they still work. Some people use rc.shutdown.local, and it's in a lot of tutorials and I want to know if I can still apply those to lion.